# Batch file to obtain IP then map drive to site specific IP

Tags: batch-file

I need to copy 3 *.xmls to a networked device at 850 sites each with the own IP schema.

The batch file needs to run, obtain the PC IP address and change last octet to .150 and then map the drive and copy the files.

I am obtaining the IP like this:

```
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('"ipconfig | findstr IP | findstr 192."') do SET LOCAL_IP=%%i
```

How can I then remove the last octet from the %LOCAL_IP% to map a drive to \\xxx.xxx.xxx.150\c$\directory ?

Answer (score 0):

just tokenize your found %local_ip%:

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=. " %%a in ("%local_ip%") do echo %%a.%%b.%%c.150 (%%d)
```

Comment: Thanks - how do I then use that in a command? So if I wanted to ping the address for example?

Comment: instead of just echoing, you can use any other command like `ping ...` or `set addr=...`